# Ansible SSH ERROR connection from control host to itself(to control host)

Tags: ansible-inventory

I can not run ping from control host to itself, getting the error, how it can be fixed?   we have boks setup on the servers(instead of sudo), also I can disable boks on the other hosts, but how I can ssh to those hosts with boks without root passwd?

error:

```
ansible control -m ping

control unreachable
```

where control is the ansibe host, so it cannot ping itself.

Comment: `getting the error` => which is ?

Comment: What does your inventory looks like for the `control` host ? And please dont retype your command/output, copy/paste them with all details.

Comment: The usual way to do things on the control host is to target `localhost` which will use from scratch `ansible_connection=local` (instead of ssh). If you want to do things differently, you either have to make sure that you can ssh on controler ip (127.0.0.1 or whatever) or to force connection to local.

Comment: how I can use :  ansible_connection=local   in order to execute playbooks

Comment: The shortest answer (for an `ini` type inventory): set the var vor the control machine with the following line: `control ansible_connection=local`. For more details: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html